# Fix php Array to string converions

Tags: php, arrays, string, warnings, notice

I am using a 2008 PHP program to take an image, annotate it and create a thumbnail of the image.

The program works but throws a notice of an Array to String conversion.

The relevant code is:

```php
$ttfont = 'Arial.TTF';
if ($ttfont != '') {
    # using ttf fonts
    $alpha   = range("a", "z");
    $alpha_u = range("A", "Z");
    $alpha = $alpha.$alpha_u.range(0, 9);
    //print_r($alpha);
    $_b = imageTTFBbox($fontsize,0,$ttfont,$alpha);
    //print_r($_b);
    $fontheight = abs($_b[7]-$_b[1]);
} else {
```

The error is in the line:

```php
$alpha = $alpha.$alpha_u.range(0, 9);
```

The `print_r`'s are my debugging attempts.

Comment: What do you expect that line to do? `range()` returns an array, not a string, you can't concatenate them.

Comment: That returns the string `"ArrayArrayArray"`

Comment: I don't see how that program could work unless you don't care what the value of `$alpha` is.

Comment: The [range()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function returns an array, so you should i.e. [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead of *glueing* it with the dot, as they were a strings.

Comment: @biesior How would array_merge help? The argument is supposed to be a string.

Comment: What is the idea behind the code? What is ti supposed to produce? Grabbing random values from thsoe ranges? Or all the values? Something else entirely?

Comment: @Barmar I wouldn't expect that question from you. First fact is that the OP is trying to merge result of function that returns an array (what you mentioned), that's what the array_merge() is for in this case, and as you pointed he can't concatenate arrays with dots.  Another thing is how it will be used, I confess, I have no idea what types of arguments `imageTTFBbox()` requires, if third arg should be array, that's ok if should be comma-separated string or something else OP should implode it to the string. Anyway I have no will to tp elaborate every basic question. Probably too old, sorry.

Comment: `$alpha` is the 4th argument to `imageTTFBbox()`, which is a text string to be measured. @biesior

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, 4th not 3rd, which doesn't change the fact, that OP is working with arrays not strings.

Comment: @biesior But the variable he's setting needs to be a string. Read the documentation of the function.

Comment: @Barmar, we both know that. We both also started from the conclusion that OP can't merge arrays like they were strings. Converting merged arrays to string is the next step to do. You should give hints to the OP, I have no problem with this simple piece of code ;)

Comment: @biesior It's not even clear that he wants to merge arrays. Until he explains what the code is supposed to do, we can't really comment usefully. Just vote to close, maybe he'll get the idea.

Comment: Well, this is not my code.  I understand that range is returning an array.

Comment: @Barmar, please, after shortening the original code looks like `$alpha = range("a", "z") . range("A", "Z") . range(0, 9)`, so it's definitelly clear what he want's to merge/concatenate. Of course you're right, that finally it should be imploded to string

Comment: @biesior My first comment asked what he wants that line to do. I'm not sure he even knows, as I don't think he wrote the code, he says it's a program that was written 13 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

you can use implode function  like

```
implode("",range("a","z"))
```

for more information see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```php
   $alpha   = implode("",range("a","z"));
   $alpha_u = implode("",range("A","Z"));
   $alpha = $alpha.$alpha_u.implode("",range(0, 9));
```